Is there a JSON setting to hide the Run button in VS Code (Python)?
enter image description here
I know how to hide and show the Run button using the UI. But is there something I can add to the settings JSON file to hide this button by default without the user needing to do anything?  (We don't need to prevent users from getting the button back manually, if they want - just hiding it by default, at least for Python files, is all we need.)
I have tried several settings, but none have hidden this particular button - the only way I've found to hide it is using the UI to do it.
Alternately, is there a setting to hide all buttons in this group?

Looks like hiding the Run button via the GUI doesn't update settings.json, which, as far as I can tell, means there isn't a related setting for that button.


Is there a JSON setting to hide the Run button in VS Code (Python)?

Not that I know of. This is probably stored in the global workspace state JSON or SQLite database file.
Related(?): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9285

The button cannot be hidden in Python extension. If you are using coderunne, you can hide the triangle button using the following setting.
"code-runner.showRunIconInEditorTitleMenu": false

